# Accessing Image in Android

Tags: android, image

i want to access image from sql database , i am parsing data through Json String.
in string i am getting data in

```
  System.Byte[]
```

and then i am reading byte data from string through base 64 This is the code

```
public Bitmap getBitmap() {
                byte[] encodeByte = Base64.decode(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
                Log.i("Model", bitmap.toString());
                return bitmap;

            }
```

in `byte[] ecodedByte` i am getting data in this formate `[75, 43, 45, 122, 96, 114, -75]` after that it is giving `Java.lang.NullPointerException` at this line

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Why you parse image to string?

Answer (score 0):

Don't parse image to `String`. Get image's url, parse data throught JSON as `String` and then use this `String` in [Picasso (click here)](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: because i am accessing other data from table too, thats why i am parsing data into json string.